# Eclipse Job started from running Job to get NotesSession

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes

I'm adding my own Java code to the Notes replicator (like the Activities sync):

```
<plugin>
   <extension
     point="com.ibm.notes.client.notesSync">
     <unit
        class="com.ibm.notes.smartfile.RunOnReplication"
        id="com.ibm.notes.smartfile.RunOnReplication"
        image="icons/SmartFile.gif"
        label="IBM SmartFile action">
     </unit>
  </extension>
</plugin>
```

This adds an entry to the replicator page that executes every time a job runs. My class looks like this:

```
public class RunOnReplication extends Job {
    public RunOnReplication(String name) {
      super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor arg0) {
        NotesSessionJob nsj = new NotesSessionJob("SmartFile Replication") {
            @Override
            protected IStatus runInNotesThread(Session s,
                IProgressMonitor monitor) throws NotesException {
            Engine engine = Activator.getDefault().getEngine();
            return engine.scheduledProcessing(s, monitor);
            }
        };
    nsj.schedule();
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
   }
}
```

Now I wonder: how can I get the monitor in the `nsj` Job to report the status to the outer class, so the progress is reported to the replicator progress bar -- or is there a different way to get to the NotesSession without creating a new job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use the NotesSessionJob. Instead of that you can also use the "old" way of instantiating the N/D java classes.

```
public class RunOnReplication extends Job {
    public RunOnReplication(String name) {
      super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor arg0) {
        try {
            NotesThread.sinitThread();
            Session session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
            //do your stuff here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do your error handling here
        } finally {
            NotesThread.stermThread();
        }
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
   }
}
```

Btw: cool idea...

Comment: Jup. I now only need to figure out how to delay the start after the mail replication has finished and I have my "mail-slave, get rid of that stuff" tool ready